# How to make the function in a lambda be called in another function used inside the body of lambda

Tags: exception, scheme, callcc

I want to using call/cc to simulating the exception handling statement: try...(throw)...exception. Here's the code:

```
(define (month n) ; check if it's a month number (1-12)
  (if (or (not (integer? n)) (< n 1) (> n 12))
    (throw -1)
    (display n)
  )
)

(define error (call/cc
   (lambda(throw)
     (begin
       (month 12)
       (month -1)
       (throw -1) ; won't be executed
       (month 10)
       (display "Hello world")
      )
     )
   )
 )

(if error
  (display Error occured!")
)
```

However, When I executed it, it showed the error (in biwascheme):

```
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "throw" [(anon), month]
```

I think that the throw in lambda is not the same as the throw in the called function "month", However, how can I solve it? Is it can be solved with making marco with some keywords? eg:

```
(define-syntax exception-handling
    (syntax-rules (throw raise error)
      ((_ body catch)
        (define (error
                  (call/cc (lambda (throw) (begin body))))
        )
        (if error (begin catch)))
    )
 )
```

Comment: kudos on the re-formatting -- and most importantly, staying engaged! While writing the code your style of putting the closing parentheses each on its line can make editing easier; but once we have the code, it's customary to put all the closing parentheses on the same line and let the indentation guide us in reading the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme, continuations are *first-class*. A captured continuation is just another value. Pass it in to your `month` function as another argument:

```
(define (month n throw) ; check if it's a month number (1-12)
  (if (or (not (integer? n)) (< n 1) (> n 12))
    (throw -1)
    (display n)))
```

And call it as

```
     ....
     (month 12 throw)
     ....
     (month 10 throw)
     ....
```

Your indentation style is not conducive to the readability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use `call-with-current-continuation` to make a "throw".

```
#lang r5rs

(define (month n) ; check if it's a month number (1-12)
  (call-with-current-continuation
    (lambda (throw)       
      (define ok (and (integer? n) (<= 1 n 12)))
      (if (not ok)
        (throw "the month number must be between 1 and 12"))
      (display n)
      (newline))))

(month 12)
(month -1)
(month 10)
(display "Hello world\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I've find the way to simulating try and exception-handling:

```
(define-syntax try
   (syntax-rules (catch)
     ((_ body catch handling)
        (let ()
          ; evaluating body and save it as an exception.
          (define except (begin body)) 
          (if (and
                (pair? except)
                (eq? (car except) 'exception))
             (handling except)
          )
        )
      )
   )
)

; returns an exception '(exception, "Error messenge")
(define (exception-content msg throw)
  (throw (cons 'exception msg)))
; throw an exception if n = 0
(define (reciprocal n throw)
  (if (= n 0)
     (exception-content "Div 0 error" throw)
     (/ 1 n)
  )
)

; f1(n) = reciprocal(n) + 1
(define (f1 n throw)
  (+ (reciprocal n throw) 1)
)

; main program 
(try ; with call/cc and the continuation variable "throw"
   (call-with-current-continuation
     (lambda (throw)
       (display (f1 2 throw))
       (newline)
       (display (f1 0 throw))

       ; the following won't be executed
       (newline)
       (display (f1 1 throw))
     )
   )

 catch
   ; exception handling
   (lambda (exception)
     (display (cdr exception))
   )
)
```

The printed result is:

```
3/2
Div 0 error
```

Comment: of course all this passing around of the `throw` references everywhere shows us, and simulates, the *dynamic* (as in, *not lexical*) nature of exceptions. :)